# Executing Selenium tests one after the other without re launching the browser through testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two testcases that has to be executed 
1.Login to an App
2.Perform some operations

Below is the design of my code:
BaseTest.java

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void openApplication() {
        System.setProperty(chrome_key,chrome_value);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

LoginPage.java

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage{
    @FindBy (xpath = "//input[@id='username']")
    WebElement userName;

    @FindBy (xpath = "//input[@id='password']")
    WebElement password;    
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void loginToApp(String username, String pwd) {

    }
}
```

Account.java:

```
public class NewAccount extends BasePage{
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[text()='Accounts']/../..")
    WebElement accountsTab;

    public NewAccount(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void createNewAccount() {    
    }
}
```

LoginToApp.java:

```
public class LoginToApp extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void a_verifyLogin() throws IOException {
        LoginPage hp = new LoginPage(driver);
        hp.loginToApp(username, password);
    }
}
```

CreateAccount.java:

```
public class CreateAccount extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void b_createAccountRecord() {
        NewAccount na = new NewAccount(driver);
        na.createNewAccount();
    }
}
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.testcases.LoginToApp"/>
      <class name="com.testcases.CreateAccount"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

With this framework structure, When I execute the testng.xml file, the first test in LoginToApp executes as expected. And When the control comes to the test in CreateAccount, the driver becomes Null and hence failing the execution of the 2nd Test.

Expected Flow:
1.Initialise Browser
2.Launch the url
3.Execute the @Test method of LoginToApp.java
4.Execute the @Test method of CreateAccount.java

Is it possible to achieve the above flow without making the WebDriver as static? If yes, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Initialise Browser  (set this under before method)
2.Launch the url      (give priority =0)
3.Execute the @Test method of LoginToApp.java  (give priority =1)
4.Execute the @Test method of CreateAccount.java( give depends on method )

depends on method only execute if your loginapp test successfully run
```